# How to add header to csv table scala spark

Tags: scala, azure, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read data from a table that is in a `csv` file. It does not have a header so when I try and query the table using Spark SQL, all the results are null.

I have tried creating a schema struct, and while it does display when I do `printschema()`, when I try and ( `select * from tableName` ) it does not work, all values are null. I have also tried the `StructType()` and `.add( colName )` instead of `StructField` and that yielded the same results.

```
        val schemaStruct1 = StructType(
            StructField( "AgreementVersionID", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "ProgramID", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "AgreementID", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "AgreementVersionNumber", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "AgreementStatusID", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "AgreementEffectiveDate", DateType, true )::
            StructField( "AgreementEffectiveDateDay", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "AgreementEndDate", DateType, true )::
            StructField( "AgreementEndDateDay", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "MasterAgreementNumber", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "MasterAgreementEffectiveDate", DateType, true )::
            StructField( "MasterAgreementEffectiveDateDay", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "MasterAgreementEndDate", DateType, true )::
            StructField( "MasterAgreementEndDateDay", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "SalesContactName", StringType, true )::
            StructField( "RevenueSubID", IntegerType, true )::
            StructField( "LicenseAgreementContractTypeID", IntegerType, true )::Nil
        )

        val df1 = session.read
            .option( "header", true )
            .option( "delimiter", "," )
            .schema( schemaStruct1 )
            .csv( LicenseAgrmtMaster )
        df1.printSchema()
        df1.createOrReplaceTempView( "LicenseAgrmtMaster" )

Printing this schema gives me this schema which is correct

root
 |-- AgreementVersionID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ProgramID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AgreementID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AgreementVersionNumber: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AgreementStatusID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AgreementEffectiveDate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- AgreementEffectiveDateDay: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AgreementEndDate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- AgreementEndDateDay: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- MasterAgreementNumber: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- MasterAgreementEffectiveDate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- MasterAgreementEffectiveDateDay: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- MasterAgreementEndDate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- MasterAgreementEndDateDay: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SalesContactName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RevenueSubID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- LicenseAgreementContractTypeID: integer (nullable = true)
```

which is correct however trying to query this gives me a table yielding only null values even though the table is not filled with nulls. I need to be able to read this table in order to join to another to complete a stored procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest go with steps below then you can change your code based on your need

```
val df = session.read.option( "delimiter", "," ).csv("<Path of your file/dir>")
val colum_names = Seq("name","id")// this is example define exact number of columns
val dfWithHeader = df.toDF(colum_names:_*)
// now you have header here and data should be also here check the type or you can cast
```